# Ionic 3 how to Vertically center text in custom ion-input?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, css-position

[image: The problem]

You can see that in the image the text in the ion-input is not centered Vertically.
The standard ion-inputs are slightly off centered to look better.

[image: Standard ionic input]

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance :D

**EDIT: I meant vertically instead of Horizontally :/**

**EDIT** Here is the code someone requested, the height and font-size are in media queries.

```
.email, .pass {
 width: 75%;
 max-width: 500px;
 border: none;
 background-color: #CC6992;
 font-family: Rubik;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #3C3C3C;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 18px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}



::placeholder {
  font-family: Rubik;
}
```

Comment: seems like they are using an absolutely positioned label for the placeholder, so you'll have to adjust it's `top` property.

Comment: Do you mean vertically center? Horizontally is left/right, vertically is up/down.

Comment: @Josheph Webber Yes! Sorry I'll edit it. My bad thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please add code as you have updated the basic ionic 3 css

Comment: Okay, I will do that.

Comment: I think It may have to do with my Font Rubik...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is:

```
.vertical-align {    
    display: flex !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}
```

You can remove the `!important`, I just used them here because I had other classes interfiering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text (horizontal: right & left) and also the placeholder, edit the native class of ionic-input :

```
.text-input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For the placeholder:

```
.text-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-input:-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-input::-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also check the [utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/) of ionic, and try to use also the attribute : `text-center`

After your edit ffor the vertical, you have to try something like this :

```
display: flex !important;
justify-content: center !important;
align-items: center !important;
height: 100%;
```